# Why my program is showing wrong output in C

Tags: c

I want a program in which the user will give three names and they will be printed in result.

I declared a string "name" and also declared that 'name' variable as an array(or I wanted to)

But when I run the program,The output I get is weird
It only accepted one name,I thought It had something to do with array declaration,so I changed 'char name[3][20];' to 'char name[20][3];' but nothing changed..

Please help me..

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct variable
{
char name[3][20];
}v;
void main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Three names \n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        scanf("%c",&v.name[i]);
        }
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
        printf("%c\t",v.name[i]);
        }
getch();
}
```

Output Image :-> [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxzXQ.jpg)

Comment: `%c` means exactly one character. Check the documentation for `scanf` and `printf` for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%c is the format string for a char data type
for printing a string you will want to use the %s format string

```
# include <stdio.h> 

int main(){
    char name [3][20];
    printf("Enter 3 names\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        scanf("%s", name[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("%s\n", name[i]);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to use `%s` instead of `%c`, (first one works with strings, second one with single chars).
2. change `printf("%c\t",v.name[i]);` to `printf("%c\t",v.name[j]);` because otherwise your loop wouldn't pass through all the names thus, print them out.